# Including Older Version of jQuery for IE7/IE8

Tags: jquery, javascript, wp-enqueue-script

I realise jQuery 2.0 dropped support for some browsers including IE7 and IE8.

I'm only using a bit of jQuery on my WordPress site, but since I need to support IE7/IE8, I was wondering what the best way was to go about including older versions of jQuery? Or should I just choose one version (like 1.9.1), that supports older and more modern browsers, and stick with that?

I'm currently injecting jQuery into my `functions.php` like so:

```
if (!is_admin()) add_action("wp_enqueue_scripts", "my_jquery_enqueue", 11);
function my_jquery_enqueue() {
    wp_deregister_script('jquery');
    wp_register_script('jquery', "http" . ($_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] == 443 ? "s" : "") . "://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js", false, null);
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
}
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use the default jQuery (as you should anyway), and you get the compatibility script for free.

Comment: Thanks for this. After reading your comment I've read a few articles about using WP's default jQuery. Completely baffled as to why this barebones theme I'm using decides to include jQuery in this way.

Answer (score 1):

Currently (WP 4.6) WordPress includes jquery 1.12.4, so as @toscho notes there are no compatibility issues with older IE browsers.

However, [it was recently announced](http://blog.jquery.com/2016/06/09/jquery-3-0-final-released/) that 1.12.4 will be the last jquery version of that branch. Sooner or later WP will have to move to jquery 3.0 branch, in which all support for IE 6-8 will have been dropped.